# Entity Framework Query with MAX

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I've been banging my head against the wall trying to translate a simple SQL Query into EF query..

Can anyone help please.. Following is the query I am trying to translate.

```
SELECT p.[UniqueId]
  ,p.[CAI]
  ,p.[HRGuid]
  ,p.[FullName]
  ,p.[Email]
  ,a.*
FROM [Participant] p
INNER JOIN 
(
    Select * FROM Assignment where assignmentNumber = 
    (Select MAX(AssignmentNumber)FROM 
    Assignment GROUP BY UniqueId)
) a
ON p.UniqueId = a.UniqueId
```

Basically I'm trying to get Participant along with their latest assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create your Participant entity using Linq-Objects. You need to customize after `AsEnumerable` in order to create your entities

```
var query = (from p in context.Participant
            join a in context.Assignment on p.UniqueId equals a.UniqueId into ag
            select new
            {
              Participant = p,
              Assignment = ag.OrderByDescending(x => x.AssignmentNumber).FirstOrDefault()
            }).AsEnumerable()
              .Select(x => new Participant(x.Participant )
                     {    
                        Assignments = new Assignment[] { x.Assignment }
                     };
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. This is indeed what I was looking for. However I do not want anonymous types. Is there any possibility I can get Entities back (Assuming I am projecting all the columns from Participant).

Comment: @Armaghan - Can you please show me the structure of Participant and Assignment entities? I modified the answer to add a linq to objects step

Comment: Participant and Assignment are POCO entities.

Comment: as simple structure is as follows:  
`class Participant () {
 String UniqueId {get; set;}
 String Email {get; set;}
 IEnumerable<Assignment> Assignments {get; set;}
}

class Assignment() {
 Int32 AssignmentNumber {get; set;}
 DateTime StartDate {get; set;}
}`

Comment: It works perfectly with a slight modification to the second select expression. Thank you very much!